# How to turn free Magento Connect extension into paid extension?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, magento-connect

This question is about upgrading an extension to latest Magento version and resubmit it as a **paid** component.

We have built an extension that works with customer credit. Currently we are offering a free version of it which is compatible up to version `1.8.1`. Going further we are now planning to upgrade it to version `1.9`

1. How long it takes to upgrade an extension to version 1.9 and how to
   resubmit it as a paid component ?
2. What it takes to make an extension a Paid version ?
3. How is the payment processed while purchasing an extension ?
4. How the pricing is decided for a paid extension ?
5. Is it advisable to go from free to paid version ?

Also what are the advantages of upgrading an extension to latest version?

Comment: you want help for free from the community to make money ? you should think about it again... i think its a bit naughty...

Comment: @roman204, its not about making money, but an overview on how to proceed with an extension which is already free and make it paid by adding soem more features and functionalities.

Comment: I agree with the OP. This is a valid question. Other questions asked here are also ultimately about making money (Magento is a webshop, to sell things, remember?)

Comment: yes its a valid question,absolutly correct, thats the reason why i dont downvoting it, but i add a comment to tell him my thought to do a little bit more research and not take the easy way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That are quite a few questions for one topic :) Try to stick to one question per topic. Although I have to admit that they are highly related.

1. This highly depends on your extension. Many extensions run with newer Magento versions without any modifications. But if you use some Magento logic which has been altered or a method which has been removed, you have to update your code. In any case, you have to test your extension thoroughly with the new Magento version. It is highly advisable to write unit tests with something like [EcomDev_PHPUnit](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit), so that you can test your extension with new versions automatically.
2. You have to have your own shop where you sell the extension. You cannot sell extension on Magento Connect directly (yet). You can just submit it there as a paid extension, but Magento Connect will simply redirect the user to your shop. There are some other options, though. You can sell your extension on [nr-apps.com](http://www.nr-apps.com/store/). Mind that [this costs (a lot)](http://www.nr-apps.com/store/list-your-magento-extensions.html). I would be careful with that approach: Netresearch already admitted that this marketplace does not really work, so that I am not sure whether they continue this service. There is one new service where you can sell extensions for a 10% fee - it is called [AveoTrade Connect Manager](https://connect20.aveo-trade.cz/). Maybe it is also possible to sell extensions on [Xtension Galaxy](https://xtensiongalaxy.com/).
3. If you use your own shop, you decide that. If you sell on a marketplace mentioned under 2, the payment is usually done via their system and you will get a regular payout.
4. Good question. There is no easy answer. Have a look at [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51525/how-to-find-the-right-price-for-a-magento-extension) as a reference.
5. This of course depends on your extension and your business model. If you think people will buy your extension and you want to become an extension provider, go for it.

Extensions should always be compatible with the latest Magento versions. Otherwise people who use the newest versions will probably not use your extensions.